# Merging several PartCover reports into a CruiseControl.Net build log

Tags: continuous-integration, cruisecontrol.net, partcover

I run a sequence of integration tests of several components as a part of a CruiseControl.Net project. Then I merge PartCover reports into the overall build report and here comes the problem: every report has assembly IDs starting from 1. As a result, I get the per-assembly statistics only for one assembly and those statistics are obviously invalid.

I tried to find a way to provide PartCover a specific assembly ID seed but did not succeed. So my only idea at the moment is to pre-process reports before merging them to add e.g. 10, 20, 30, etc. to the assembly IDs.

Does anybody know any smarter way of resolving this?

Answer (score 1):

A bit late in the day but have you looked at [ReportGenerator](http://www.palmmedia.de/Net/ReportGenerator)  that has the ability to merge partcover reports into a nice output